# Why can't I stop people from inviting me to group chats on kik?

Tags: instant-messaging, kik-messenger

Someone has been harassing me on kik all week by continually adding me group chats that I did not ask to be part of. The person is blocked, but they are still able to add me to group chats against my will - I don't have the option of accepting or not, it just happens.

If I have to abandon the platform and find another way to talk with my friends overseas I will, but I'm hoping there's some way I can stop this. (And yes, I've reported the offending user to kik support, but they're terribly slow and now it's the weekend...)

I apologize in advance if this isn't a good community for this question, I just can't find an answer anywhere else I can't believe that there isn't one.

Comment: Never heard of kik.  Those instant messengers are a dime a dozen.  Why not try your luck with something better like Google Hangouts (my preference - works really well), Skype, Whatsapp, Tango....?

Comment: I have been quite disappointed with the contact management aspect of Kik for quite some time. Unfortunately, unless and until the developer gives people more control over who can see them and add them to conversations I'm afraid you're stuck. For me, I'm looking for a better cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you cannot. Either wait out the harassment, don't open the app for a while, or switch discussion platforms with the people you care to talk to. All unsatisfying solutions, but... they are the only ones.

Answer (score -2):

If you want them to stop why don't you make a new kik? I have done the same blocked and it still happens I don't understand why but just make a new one or simply email kik messenger and report that person.